# How to iterate over files with Promises in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise, q, fs-extra

I have a folder with a bunch of JSON files that looks like this:

```
|
|-foo.json
|-bar.json
|-qux.json
|-baz.json
|-zot.json
```

Each JSON file has a property `children` that points to some of the other JSON files, so that they all describe a tree. Now, say that this is foo.json:

***foo.json***

```
{
    "id": "foo",
    ...
    "children": [
        "bar.json",
        "baz.json"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Say that bar.json doesn't have a `children` property and that this is baz.json:

***baz.json***

```
{
    "id": "baz",
    ...
    "children": [
        "zot.json"
    ]
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to write a Node program that will list the descendants of a given JSON file. Meaning that for `foo.json` it should output `[bar, baz, zot]`.

I'm using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) to read the JSON files.

If I were doing this synchronously I'd write something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

var descendants = ["foo.json"];
for(var k = 0; k < descendants.length; k++){
    var obj = fs.readJsonSync(descendants[k]);
    if(obj.children) descendants.concat(obj.children);
}
return descendants;
```

***Note:*** For simplicity, assume that the script executes at the root of the directory where the json files are

But I'd like to do this using promises. My problem is I can't seem to resolve the promise for each file and add the result to the `descendants` variable before the loop ends, of course because the loop is synchronous.

What is the proper way to do this using promises? In particular, I've been trying to use a combination of [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and `reduce` to help me do this, but I've been unable to write the code properly so far.

Comment: You can use a `for … of` loop and async/await. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also take a look at this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-graph. I would read all the json files and build a dependency graph using this library and then use `graph.dependenciesOf` to get the dependencies of any file.